# Removing "WOO_" Prefix When Pulling Orders With REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We're currently in the process of tying WooCommerce with a Fulfillment/Distribution center.  We've successfully utilized API credentials to allow WooCommerce to relay all information from new orders that come through, but there's one problem... the order ID's being pulled have "WOO_" (eg. WOO_4564, WOO_4566, etc.) right before them, and the fulfillment center needs this removed for their system to work properly.

Is there a simple solution to achieving this task?  Unfortunately I don't have access to the backend on their part so I'm hoping this is doable from WordPress/WooCommerce.

Pulling orders from wc-api/v1/ and wc-api/v2/ doesn't result in a "WOO_" prefix, which is confusing me even more.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are getting the following responses:

```
$order = $wc_api->get_order( 777 );

print_r( $order);

/* response
stdClass Object
(
    [order] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 777
            [order_number] => #777........
```

you can do following to remove the prefix from the order array :

```
$order['id'] = trim($order['id'], "WOO_");
```